# Plugins in IONIC project not added

Tags: ionic-framework

I am new to ionic framework. When I was adding any plugin using cli as

> ionic plugin add https://github.com/ccsoft/cordova-facebook.git

I get the following error:

```
Repository "https://github.com/ccsoft/cordova-facebook.git" checked out to gitef "master".
shell.js: internal error
Error: EXDEV, cross-device link not permitted 'C:\Users\Miteshpc\AppData\Local\emp\git\1434622511690\LICENSE'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.renameSync (fs.js:636:18)
    at C:\Users\Miteshpc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\shelljs\src\mv.js:77:8
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object._mv (C:\Users\Miteshpc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\nde_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\shelljs\src\mv.js:53:11)
    at Object.mv (C:\Users\Miteshpc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\noe_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\shelljs\src\common.js:186:23)
    at C:\Users\Miteshpc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\ordova-lib\src\plugman\util\plugins.js:53:19
    at _fulfilled (C:\Users\Miteshpc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\nde_modules\q\q.js:787:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\Miteshpc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_moules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:816:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\Miteshpc\AppData\Roaming\npm\nde_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:749:13)
```

Comment: Possible duplicated with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30801307/upgrade-cordova-cannot-install-plugins-from-git-urls-anymore
roll back cordova to 5.0.0

Comment: I published the answer here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30801307/upgrade-cordova-cannot-install-plugins-from-git-urls-anymore/30958837#30958837

It will work for you

Comment: Yes I did rollback to cordova 5.0.0 the problem is resolved

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem trying to add the Facebook plugin for oAuth. The real reason of the problem is still unknown for me but following the instructions of @Pian0_M4n it worked for me, it's a good workaround to the problem. Here is the link:

[Upgrade cordova: cannot install plugins from git urls anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30801307/upgrade-cordova-cannot-install-plugins-from-git-urls-anymore/30958837#30958837)

Good luck!