# Visual Studio 2015 won't work with Tools For Apache Cordova

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova, taco, tools-for-apache-cordova

I did the full installation of VS 2015 Enterprise + Tools for Apache Cordova. When I open or create any project It won't build and even show the Ripple Emulator or Device information on the Run button.

I already did a full reinstall and still the same.

When I click the Dependency Check button at the Configuration Window says everything is OK.

When I try to build:

> npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600 1>  npm ERR! argv "node"
>   "C:\Users\%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js"
>   "-g" "install" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ApacheCordovaTools\packages\vs-tac" "--loglevel" "warn" 1>  npm ERR! node v0.12.2 1>  npm ERR! npm 
>   v2.12.0 1>  npm ERR! undefined is not a function 1>  npm ERR!
>   1>RUNMDAINSTALL : npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error
>   at: 1>  npm ERR!     https://github.com/npm/npm/issues 1>  npm ERR!
>   Please include the following file with any support request: 1>  npm
>   ERR!     C:\Users\%UserProfile%\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp10\BlankCordovaApp10\npm-debug.log 1> 
>   ------ npm install failed. Exit code: 1 1>  ------ Package installation failed. Retrying... 1>  npm WARN uninstall not installed
>   in C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules: "vs-tac" 1>  npm ERR!
>   Windows_NT 6.3.9600 1>  npm ERR! argv "node"
>   "C:\Users\%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js"
>   "-g" "install" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ApacheCordovaTools\packages\vs-tac" "--loglevel" "warn" 1>  npm ERR! node v0.12.2 1>  npm ERR! npm 
>   v2.12.0 1>  npm ERR! undefined is not a function 1>  npm ERR!
>   1>RUNMDAINSTALL : npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error
>   at: 1>  npm ERR!     https://github.com/npm/npm/issues 1>  npm ERR!
>   Please include the following file with any support request: 1>  npm
>   ERR!     C:\Users\%UserProfile%\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp10\BlankCordovaApp10\npm-debug.log 1> 
>   ------ npm install failed. Exit code: 1 1>  ------ Package installation failed. Retrying... 1>  npm WARN uninstall not installed
>   in C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules: "vs-tac" 1>C:\Program
>   Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(287,5):
>   error : Error installing local npm package. 1>MSBUILD : cordova-build
>   error BLD401: Error : BLD00401 : Could not find module
>   'C:\Users\%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\app.js'.
>   Please Go to Tools --> Options --> Tools for Apache Cordova -->
>   Cordova Tools --> Clear Cordova Cache and try building again.
>
> ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

I did clean the cache using the Configuration button but still the same. When a run `npm cache clear` the package install, but the Run Button don't show device information as I said before.

**EDIT:**

@Subhag Oak Thank you! This brought back the menu options from Run button, but still errors when I try to Run/Build:

> ------ npm install of vs-tac@1.0.0 from 
>   C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO
>   14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\APACHECORDOVATOOLS\packages\vs-tac completed. 1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error BLD401: Error : BLD00401 :
>   Could not find module
>   'C:\Users\FilipeAugusto\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\app.js'.
>   Please Go to Tools --> Options --> Tools for Apache Cordova -->
>   Cordova Tools --> Clear Cordova Cache and try building again.
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: Is this a clean install or have you upgraded from RC build? We have an issue like this (Run button just displaying 'start' and nothing else) when customers have upgraded from RC to RTM build. Please let us know as we are trying to investigate into the issue.

Comment: It's a full instalation of the final version! I removed the entire stuff from the RC before the install. I Also removed the 2013 version before the instalation.

Comment: Please Go to Tools --> Options --> Tools for Apache Cordova --> Cordova Tools --> Clear Cordova Cache

Comment: and see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31530014/unable-to-start-debugging-in-visual-studio-rtm-for-cordova-app/31630494#31630494

Comment: @GregorValentin as I said, this didn't work.

Comment: Sorry, didn't read carefully. Check my Answer on the other Post. Check Answer from "Jon Z" too.

Comment: I solved this issue with this steps:
1. Copy `vs-tac` folder from: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ApacheCordovaTools\Packages\` 
to the AppData roaming folder.

2. I opened a VS 2015 Developer Prompt to the AppData\roaming folder where I had copied the `vs-tac` package and run 
    `npm install`

Comment: This issue has resurfaced in [Update 6](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35393247/304683) - BLD0041 (could not find module - `C:\Users\%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\app.js` ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We think, we have a workaround for this. Can you try the following solution:

- Close all VS instances
- cd "%localappdata%\Microsoft\Phone Tools"
- rename CoreCon folder
- Launch VS again.

Let us know if this fixes the issue?

Comment: This solved half of the issue, please see the edit above!

Comment: You're a life saver @Subhag Oak.

Answer (score 6):

I solved this issue with this steps:
1. Copy `vs-tac` folder from: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ApacheCordovaTools\Packages\` 
to the **AppData roaming folder**.

2. I opened a VS 2015 Developer Prompt to the AppData\roaming folder where I had copied the `vs-tac` package and run 
   `npm install`

Comment: I am unable to install vs-tac. Getting this error - The edge module has not been pre-compiled for node.js version v5.3.0.

Comment: Exactly the same as Pratik Bhattacharya

Comment: When your saying Copy to Roaming folder, do we need to copy it to `C:\Users\hifnin\AppData\Roaming` or `C:\Users\hifnin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules` ?

Answer (score 3):

To fix This problem close VS first then
copy folder 
vs-tac 
from

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ApacheCordovaTools\Packages\
```

To

```
C:\Users\ASUS S550C\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
```

Then if you cannot see folder named cordova in new path

1- open CMD or Termianl and Write

```
cd C:\Users\ASUS S550C\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
npm install -g cordova
```

2- Then write

```
  cd C:\Users\ASUS S550C\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova
    npm install
```

This will fix the problem

**Note: to use npm you need to install [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/)**

Answer (score 2):

Started this by globally installing Cordova and then the vs-tac which seemed to be missing (not sure global installation of Cordova is required though).
Info from here (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4f97d8c5-6069-49ee-a065-283741fd483f/unable-to-build-my-first-cordova-app-in-vs-2015?forum=ToolsForApacheCordova):

```
npm install -g cordova
npm install -g "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ApacheCordovaTools\packages\vs-tac"
```

Then it was giving the following error:

> EXDEV, cross-device link not permitted

Luckily there is guidance on how to solve this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/30958837/2270404):

```
C:\Temp>git clone https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-fast-canvas.git
```

Then go to the project folder and run the following:

```
cordova plugin add C:\Temp\phonegap-plugin-fast-canvas\
```

And it's working!