# ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(285,5): error : Error installing local npm package

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, visual-studio-2015, ionic2

When I click on the run option on visual studio i am getting the following error. Please help me to solve this issue,

`1>  Success: platform check for edge.js: node.js ia32 v0.12.9
1>  C:\Users\Shanmuga Sundaram\AppData\Roaming\npm\vs-tac-cli -> C:\Users\Shanmuga Sundaram\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\vs-tac-cli.cmd
1>  npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
1>  npm ERR! argv "C:\\Users\\Shanmuga Sundaram\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\MDA\\vs-npm\\2.14.9\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Shanmuga Sundaram\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\MDA\\vs-npm\\2.14.9\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "-g" "install" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\IDE\\Extensions\\ApacheCordovaTools\\packages\\vs-tac" "--loglevel" "warn"
1>  npm ERR! node v0.12.9
1>  npm ERR! npm  v2.14.9
1>  npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID
1>  npm ERR! peerinvalid The package webpack@2.1.0-beta.22 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
1>  npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer html-webpack-plugin@2.22.0 wants webpack@*
1>  npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-webpack@1.8.0 wants webpack@^1.1.0 || ^2 || ^2.1.0-beta
1>  npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer sass-loader@3.2.3 wants webpack@^1.12.6 || ^2.1.0-beta
1>  npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer string-replace-loader@1.0.5 wants webpack@1 || 2 || ^2.0.0-beta || ^2.1.0-beta
1>  npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer webpack-dev-server@2.1.0-beta.3 wants webpack@^2.1.0-beta
1>  npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer webpack-dev-middleware@1.8.3 wants webpack@1 || ^2.1.0-beta
1>  npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
1>  npm ERR!     C:\Users\Shanmuga Sundaram\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\MDA\vs-npm\2.14.9\npm-debug.log
1>  ------ npm install failed. Exit code: 1
1>  ------ Package installation failed. Retrying...
1>  unbuild vs-tac@1.0.42
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(285,5): error : Error installing local npm package.
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : module.js:338
1>  module.js:338
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  throw err;
1>      throw err;
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  ^
1>            ^
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error BLD401: Error : BLD00401 : Could not find module 'C:\Users\Shanmuga Sundaram\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\app.js'. Please Go to Tools --> Options --> Tools for Apache Cordova --> Cordova Tools --> Clear Cordova Cache and try building again.
1>  Error Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Shanmuga Sundaram\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\app.js'
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
1>      at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
1>      at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
1>      at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at startup (node.js:129:16)
1>      at startup (node.js:129:16)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at node.js:814:3
1>      at node.js:814:3
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========`

Comment: If anyone clicking on down do let me know the mistakes? StackOverflow should have a feature like getting comments on downvote

Comment: Have you tried this `Please Go to Tools --> Options --> Tools for Apache Cordova --> Cordova Tools --> Clear Cordova Cache and try building again.`?

Comment: I tried many times still getting the same error. I am thinking because of proxy this error may came

Comment: Seems related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31679802/visual-studio-2015-wont-work-with-tools-for-apache-cordova